# My Ubuntu won't boot it only boots to busybox

Tags: 18.04, busybox, rufus

[Video to show what is going on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ibS4Vlq5nCw)

So I got ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my HP Pavillion (Model 13-128nr) and I just did a fresh install (Using Rufus) to my Usb drive and it won't boot it just goes to BusyBox

Comment: hello and welcome to the forum. so more info is required to help you such as what hardware are you trying this on (laptop modle ect.) and what version of ubuntu did you use to make your bookable usb (19.04,18.04 etc.) and did you try compatibility mode edit: safe graphics mode (not compatibility mode that's linux mint)

Comment: Hello wraith3690 001, what exactly is compatibility mode?

Comment: I meant safe graphics mode (derp) should be in the grub menu list second from the top

Comment: ok i'll try booting from that in the GRUB menu

Answer (score 2):

Please start by checking that the download was good. You can use `md5sum` according to the following link,

[Ubuntuhashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

> I looked at your video clip, but it was somewhat difficult to see the
>   output. I think you tried to create a persistent live drive with
>   Rufus, and there was an error output similar to the following:
>
> ```
> (initramfs) mount: mounting /cow on /root failed: invalid argument
> overlay mount failed
> ```
>
> If this happened you are adviced to run **Rufus** such that it does
>   not try to create a persistent live drive. You can use **'dd mode'**
>   in Rufus, and it will create a live-only drive. **'dd mode' is cloning**, a very
>   reliable way to create a USB boot drive.

Or you can use another tool, for example

- in Windows: **[Win32 Disk Imager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb)**
- in Ubuntu:

  - the **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator**
  - **Disks** alias `gnome-disks`
  - **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/)** can create both a live-only drive and a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS.

---

Rufus should be able to create a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10, which will be released next month. See also [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=42&p=13891342#post13891342).